# Setup project with crystal reports and VS2010 fails to register crystal dlls

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, installation

I built some crystal reports in VS2010, and made a setup project for it. It deploys fine on my dev machine, but I get the following error while trying to install it on the client machine.

[image]

I have googled this error for sometime and found that the VC++ 2005 redistributables are a prereq. I have added these merge modules to my setup project but I still get the same error.

[image]

I have also added .NET 4.0 as a prerequisite, and still get the same error. Anybody has any ideas?

My dev machine is running Windows 7, and I am trying to deploy it on a Windows server 2008 R2 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else's reference, I ended up adding Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET 4.0 as a prerequisite and just make the user download it if they dont have it installed. I also had to add a .NET 4.0 prerequisite (not the client profile) and of course the merge modules (CRRuntime_13_0.msm). If anyone has a better way of getting this to work, I am still interested. Thanks!

Comment: quick question, do you have to register the version of crystal report to be able to deploy it? I'm not sure it is included with VS2010 and I don't understand the meaning of the "register" button in the menu...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.. I didn't have to register anything manually.. , but all I did was download and run the CR for VS2010 from http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp. To get my reports working on other machines straight from an installer... I simply changed the prerequisites of the installer to include Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.0 (not client profile)... You also have to include CRRuntime_13_0.msm.. Not sure if this is helpful or not..

Comment: actually I found out that you have to get a written note from SAP to be "allowed" to distribute the runtime. To do so, you need to register your "runtime" (included in the license of VS2010) on their website.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp

Answer (score 0):

The merge modules you have added are from VC++ **2008** redistributable, not **2005**.

You can download the correct redistributable from the following link:
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5638)

That contains the required `Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm`, `Microsoft_VC80_MFC_x86.msm`, `Microsoft_VC80_ATL_x86.msm` and `Microsoft_VC80_OpenMP_x86.msm`, as noted [here](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Using+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Merge+Modules+%28MSM%29+to+create+a+Setup+project).

AFAIK, There's no need to .NET 4.0 as a prerequisite, at least for Crystal Reports Runtime for VS 2010. The above redistributable added to the setup project, all that error messages are gone.

NOTE:
To add the VC++ 2005 redistributable to the VS setup project, a corresponding bootstrapper package should be added in the following folder (for VS 2010):
%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages

Or *%ProgramFiles(x86)%* folder on 64-bit Windows.

UPDATE:
To create a prerequisite bootstrapper package, see the following links (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854698/how-to-install-visual-studio-2010-setup-project-with-ms-access-database-on-a-com/13854971#13854971)):
[Deploying Custom made Visual Studio prerequisites using Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://udaykirant.blogspot.se/2010/04/deploying-custom-made-visual-studio.html)
[Creating Bootstrapper Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I installed CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_8.msi on 64bit and finally worked