# Is the "Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assembly" the same thing as the "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, excel, excel-2007, oledb

I'm creating an installer in Visual Studio 2010 for an application that needs to read data from xlsx spreadsheets using an OleDbConnection (the connection string looks like `"Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='filename';Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0';HDR='Yes'";`

On my machines, I've been installing the "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" from [this Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734).

In Visual Studio the list of available prerequisites at Installer->Properties->Prerequisites doesn't include the "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components", but it does include the "Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies" (also available at [this Microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18346)).

My question is: will listing the "Microsoft Office 2007 PIA" as a prerequisite allow my OleDbConnection to work for folks who don't already have the "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You are querying an excel file via ADO.Net and need the data access driver shipped. To do that you can [embed Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable into your setup program as a prerequisite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854698/how-to-install-visual-studio-2010-setup-project-with-ms-access-database-on-a-com).

The 2007 PIA would allow you to create and automate an excel instance via COM interop, which is more powerful (e.g. you get formula cell updates) but a lot slower than the OLEDB interface of Excel.

Comment: Drat! Any idea whether there's an easy way to list the appropriate ADO.NET data access driver as a prerequisite so that the installer will install it when it's not found on the target system?