# Automatically install access database when creating setup file in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, installation

I Have created a c# application which is using access database.
I have deploy the application successfully.
what I want is install the access database automatically in other users computer  automatically.

I have tried to change the app.config files connection string and no use..:(
help me

Comment: What do you mean by automatically??? you need to install the database and give its path in app config

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but if your database is part of your solution you can copy it to the output directory:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific. Did you install the application using installer? Copying and pasting?

Maybe these would help:

1. [StackOverflow - "How to install visual studio 2010 setup project with MS Access database on a computer which is not having Office 2010 installed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13854698/1909995)
2. [CodeProject - Deploy your Application and Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database)
3. [MSDN Forums - "How to attach sql database file to creating .exe setup in c#"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5808f536-f48d-4869-adf2-13b876984ae9/)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the access db to a folder in programdata with the setup. Connect to this db in your code. You don't need a connectionstring in app.config if the user is not allowed to specify the db path.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Your setup should be able to deploy to a programdata folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create .exe Setup Project  of your **Dot Net** Application which is using **MS Access DATA BASES**. then simply follow this steps. Please read this one for a moment before to proceed these steps.[Connect with MS Access Data Base in Dot net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275557/c-sharp-inserting-data-from-a-form-into-an-access-database/22140884#22140884).
When you are going to create the exe file then your data base connection string should be like this(means there should be no directory in @"Data source, Just direct put the name of your data base, because in .exe file when you add your data base file, then it is in the same directory.

```
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
     @"Data source=MyDataBase.accdb";
```

1. Right click on your solution file. *(like in Solution Explorer "Solution 'MyProject' ")*
2. Select Add -->New Project -->Other Project Types
3. Select "Setup"
4. A New project will be added named setup (*with a new tab added to
   editor as File System )*
5. Now right click on application folder -->select add -->select folder
   new folder will be added under application folder * Now Right click
   on newly added folder -->select add -->select file * Add File dialog
   will be popup
6. Select your Db file *(means from a "Browse" Button there go and select your Access Data Base )*
7. Select Setup project and build.. Now your
       installer will have your DB.
8. You can also install it from there.