# syntax error insert into database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have some problem when I want to insert data into database ACCESS using C#

The message error is:

> System.data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): error de syntaxe dans l'instruction INSERT INTO...........

Does someone know what the problem is?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace First_cnx
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Reeda\Documents\Warface.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO [membre] (Player, Password, Gun, Claass) VALUES('" + player.Text + "', '" + password.Text + "', '" + gun.Text + "', '" + kind.Text + "')");

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved !");
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: print out your sql statement

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Could you give your`[membre]` table structure?

Comment: plus what marc_s said!

Comment: @user2941651 yeah i give it

Comment: @marc_s should i do wht ?

Comment: Looks like you have *a syntax error* in the SQL: `Claass` instead of expected `Class`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko no no i change it but not work :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Inserting Data from a form into an access Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275557/c-sharp-inserting-data-from-a-form-into-an-access-database)

Comment: Have you tryed to run your query directly in access? access error message aren't really good but by doing it in access you can be sure the query itself is good

Comment: @Reda in your class field in the UI, enter this: `whatever'); drop table membre; --`. This will show you what marc_s means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password is a [reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html). Try the Query like this:

```
command.CommandText = String.Format(@"INSERT INTO [membre] (Player, [Password], Gun, Claass) VALUES('" + player.Text + "', '" + password.Text + "', '" + gun.Text + "', '" + kind.Text + "')");
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides on your insert values, I think this happens because `Password` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266?wa=wsignin1.0) in OLE DB Provider. You should use it with square brackets like `[Password]`. The best solution is to change your column name to a *non-reserved* word.

### But more important

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You don't need to use `String.Format` in your case as well since you didn't format your string.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

```
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    // Set your CommandText property.
    // Define and add your parameter values.
    // Open your OleDbConnection.
    // Execute your query.
}
```

Comment: I think he uses String.Format to avoid string Concatenation which would take more memory space and is slower. Even if this usage of String.Format isn't the usual way.

Comment: @CptVince Argh, maybe.. He saved 3 concatenation, huh? :) Still think it is unnecessary.

Comment: i don't know if this is right but i use even for this little concatenation.[code]String.Format(@"INSERT INTO [membre] (Player, [Password], Gun, Claass) VALUES('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')", player.Text, password.Text, gun.Text, kind.Text);[/code] With normal String Concatenation it would be with the + ", " + thing over 9 concatenations i think.

Comment: @CptVince When you use parameterized queries, you will not need to format your string ;) Use them, **USE THEM ALWAYS**!

Comment: Jap sorry you are right i just thought about the concatenation.