# C# asp.net logging clients' activities

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, relational-database, primary-key

Database tables: Registration & Purchase 
(Using Unique ID ranged 1-10000 as primary key and foreign key connecting to two tables)

How can I put on unique ID to my Purchase tables when  tourists with corresponding ID do the online purchase?

I am using visual studio to work out the asp.net. However, how can I store the clients Unique ID to identify their logging activities?

```
        string result = "0";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb";
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select ID from Registration where Name ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";

        string getValue = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        if (getValue != null)
        {
            result = getValue.ToString();
        }
        Session.Add("UserID", result);

        command.CommandText = "select * from Registration where Name ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";

        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have't input the Username.");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("you havn't input the Password.");
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {   

            MessageBox.Show("Username and password is valid");
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
            Response.Redirect("Loginpage.aspx", true);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is not matched");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Client activities means ?

Comment: I want to save the client's corresponding unique ID so that i can put on the unique ID when the clients do the online shopping activities

Comment: Get the Session Id using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId` this will be unique per user per session.

Comment: use it in the login page??? and then how can i mark the corresponding unique ID into the Purchase tables><

Comment: yes, and that will exist till the User ends its session. So if the User have a Unique ID and he is going to purchase any product you can bind that Id with the Purchase Table

Comment: love u so much. i try it@@

Comment: BUT , how can i use this code?? i am very new to C#...&asp.net. Do u have example?   I just want to build a session based on clients' Unique ID

Comment: I have added the code upon ..... could u tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to get your Registration (client) ID :

```
public static string GetClientId()
{
    string result = "0";
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sim\Desktop\Web.accdb";
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = "select ID from Registration where Name ='" + TextBox1.Text + "' and Password ='" + TextBox2.Text + "'";

    string getValue = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    if (getValue != null)
    {
        result = getValue.ToString();
    }
    conn.Close();
    return result;
}
```

You can save that ID in the Session using :

```
Page.Session["UserID"] = GetClientId();
```

Then once the purchase is made, you can save it by retrieving that value using :

```
string id = Page.Session["UserID"];
```

Finally, when a purchase is made, you will need to INSERT it in the database. To learn how to do this, you can look at this : [C# Inserting Data from a form into an access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275557/c-sharp-inserting-data-from-a-form-into-an-access-database)

Comment: Yes that's my ideas. However, i want to know how to Build a session for the logged users to mark down their ID into Purchase tables.   I don't have the ideas...

Comment: Ok I added more details in my answer

Comment: i am so new... can i ask what is the meaning of Getvalue exist?  and Page.Session["UserID"] = GetClientId();  <-- the UserID is the fields name of Purchase?

Comment: getValue is just a variable holding the result of your query. ExecuteScalar is the important keyword in this code because it allows to get a single value instead of a row/table. About Page.Session, I suggest reading : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: can u help me see the above code?? how can i use two command.commandtext ?

Comment: Each time you define a CommandText, you should call ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNonQuery to execute that command. So to use 2 commands, you will need to define a command, execute it, define another, execute it.

Comment: Session["UserId"] = Purchase table "Unique no." fields . how can i make it?    and also should i use the public static ?  whether i can use the variable in the same project (visual studio) other page?