# Distribute application without installing CrystalReports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, installation

i'm developing a application and to generate reports, i'm using Crystal Reports. I'm trying to generate my application and distribute it, and I want to avoid the user  to install the Crystal Reports Runtime Environment to see all reports.

I'm developing this app on Visual Studio 2010 .NET, C# and i'm using Crystal Reports CRforVS_13_0_6.

So... i'm trying to discover if it's possible to (and if is, how i can make it):

1. How to build my application with Merged Modules from SAP (Crystal Reports), to avoid user to install the Crystal Reports Runtime;
2. How i can make a silent/quiet install of Crystal Reports with my Application Installer;

I've found those links, but didn't help me:

[Using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 Merge Modules (MSM) to create a Setup project](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Using+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Merge+Modules+%28MSM%29+to+create+a+Setup+project)

[Run/display Crystal Report 9 on client machine without installing Crystal Reports](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/visual-basic-4-5-6/threads/436541/rundisplay-crystal-report-9-on-client-machine-without-installing-it)

I know it would be easy to resolve this, but it really gonna be a headache to install on various machines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add merge modules of [CRforVS_mergemodules_13_0_6.zip](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_mergemodules_13_0_6.zip) to your setup project. (Localization files are not mandatory.)

And as noted in your above link, you also need to add [VC++ 2005 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5638) to the setup project. (See the note in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748632/setup-project-with-crystal-reports-and-vs2010-fails-to-register-crystal-dlls/18954906#18954906) for more detail.)

With that, Crystal Reports installation is silent. But when run, `setup.exe` will prompt user to accept VC++ 2005 redistributable license agreement. I don't think that can or should be removed.